# Indexing tweets from mongodb to Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, kibana

i have been working on a monitoring platform using logstash elasticsearch and kibana, the idea is to stream tweets and have a real time dashboard, everything here works just fine, now i want to store the tweets on mongodb and index them with elasticsearch, i've already done the first step of storing tweets, configuring mongodb as the output of logstash, but i can't seem to find a way to index this data with elasticsearch, i've looked for so many tutorials but i could't find a solution, if someone can help i would be really gratefull

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to:

1. Create an elastic search index
2. Read your tweets from mongodb
3. Index the tweets in elastic search

I'm guessing you already know how to do no. 2. For no. 1 you can either use the [REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html), or any number of [APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html) available, depending on what the rest of your app is written in or what you are comfortable with.

For no. 3 is the same [thing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html).

I'm using the Javascript API with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) package.